# How do you configure commitlint to ignore certain commit messages such as any that contain the string "WIP"?

Tags: git, lint

We are using commitlint to enforce a naming convention on our commits, however, I can figure out how to allow it to ignore commit messages that contain "WIP".

https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint/blob/master/docs/reference-configuration.md

```
   /*
   * Functions that return true if commitlint should ignore the given message.
   */
  ignores?: ((message: string) => boolean)[];
```

This is our current commit lint configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ['@commitlint/config-conventional'],
  rules: {
    'subject-case': [2, 'never', ['start-case', 'pascal-case']],
  },
  ignores: [],
};
```

What is example syntax to add this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax is given by the type information provided by `ignores?: ((message: string) => boolean)[];`.

You need to add a function that takes a string argument `message`, does something with it, then returns a boolean. An example:

```
ignores: [
    (message) => message.includes('WIP')
]
```

This would add a function that returns `true` if the message has `WIP` anywhere in it, causing it to be ignored.

Comment: that worked!  i was close in my syntax, just couldn't quite get it 100% correct.  thanks!

Comment: Note that this does not check for whole-word matches, so it would also match something like `WIPBLAH`. To prevent that issue, you could use a regex, e.g. `message => /\bWIP\b/i.test(message)`

Comment: Pardon the further question, but what would be the syntax to ingore e. g. a certain commit hash? The commitlint documentation doesn't say much and I didn't find the structure of the `commit` type referenced.

Comment: Any way to do this through the `commitlintrc.json` file?